# Failed to start loading kernel modules

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, kernel-modules

After updating Arch Linux xfce4 has been crashed and When I reboot the machine I got this message

> Failed to start loading kernel modules

This is the output of `uname -a`

> Linux NasserLaptop 4.8.4-1ARCH #1SMP PREEMPT Sat Oct 22 18:26:57 CEST 2016 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Output of `pacman -Q Linux

> linux 4.8.6-1

I have tried `pacman -S linux` and remount the /boot but still have the same problem

Comment: `/boot` wasn't mounted when you upgraded the kernel. Chroot in, mount `/boot` and run `pacman -S linux`.

Comment: When I try `arch-chroot` it gives me command not found

Comment: You have to run it from a live medium... See: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root

Comment: I have created a dir in /many/boot then mount the /dev/sda1 and then pacman -S linux the. Exit chroot and `genfstab /many/boot >> /etc/fstab`and umount it then reboot but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved ,Thank to u guys 
I have booted from USB then remounting the partitions as in installation then generate fstab file and edit it to add /boot then `arch-chroot` and
`pacman -S linux`
The problem was that boot partition didn't mount correctly and I have to edit fstab file to add it

[My post and more details here in the Arch forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219194)